# Selecting values from one table only if a column does not match the values in the column of another table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT u.name, u.lastname, u.username 
FROM users AS u, inmeeting AS i 
WHERE i.memo='7' AND i.user = u.keyid
```

To get all user data if the keyid for that user is in the table inmeeting (which means the user was present) for the id of that particular meeting (this would be why i.memo = 7).

Now I want to write another query that gets me all the user data of all OTHER people that were not in that meeting. I wrote this like so:

```
SELECT u.name, u.lastname, u.username 
FROM users AS u, inmeeting AS i 
WHERE i.memo='7' AND i.user <> u.keyid
```

However this query gets me EVERY user twice!! I don't understand what I'm doing wrong or how to do it right (well, I supposed this last one can be done with a subquery, but I was hoping for something a little bit more elegant). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try it with

```
SELECT 
  u.name, u.lastname, u.username
FROM 
  users AS u
WHERE 
  u.keyid NOT IN (SELECT i.user FROM inmeeting WHERE i.memo='7')
```

Comment: jaja That is exactly what I did. Good to know we agreed. I'll check your answer as correct as it does what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Best to use a LEFT OUTER JOIN and check for no match (ie, check for NULL in the WHERE clause for a column in the LEFT JOINED table):-

```
SELECT u.name, u.lastname, u.username 
FROM users AS u
LEFT OUTER JOIN inmeeting AS i 
ON i.user = u.keyid
AND i.memo='7' 
WHERE i.user IS NULL;
```

Comment: This was what I was asking for (without the subquery). I'll try it if I can, but since the other way works, I keep that. Thank you for the answer!!

Comment: Well, as far as i tested in this fiddle [link]http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b332/1  (since i had the same idea) it does not work :(

Comment: My fault. Fixed it now. This should be faster than using a sub query.